# WCF REST => Method = Delete => (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#, wcf, http-delete

I'm performing GET, POST and DELETE operations from my WCF REST service. While GET & POST works well, DELETE is not working.

From my client application, when i try to call delete it says below error.
**Error Message:** The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

**My code:**

**Data contract:**

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", UriTemplate = "users/", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[OperationContract]
string DeleteUser(UserInfo userinfo);
```

**Implementation:**

```
public string DeleteUser(UserInfo userinfo)
{
    string sResult = "";

    try
    {
        UserDataAccess dataAccess = new UserDataAccess();

        sResult = dataAccess.DeleteUser(userinfo.GEId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        oLog.LogError(ex, true);
        sResult = ex.Message;
    }

    return sResult;
}
```

**Consuming Code:**

```
protected void btDeleteAsJson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserInfo user = new UserInfo();

    user.GEId = Convert.ToInt32(txtGEID.Text);

    JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string output = jsSerializer.Serialize(user);

    SendMessageDeleteJson(apiUrl, output);
}

public void SendMessageDeleteJson(string endPoint, string output)
{
    string data = output;

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

    HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest1(endPoint, bytes.Length, "application/json");

    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string message = String.Format("DELETE failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
            throw new ApplicationException(message);
        }

        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        string sResponseStream = reader.ReadToEnd();

        lblDeleteSuccess.Text = "Success! User has beed deleted";
    }
}

private HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest1(string endPoint, Int32 contentLength, string ContentType)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);

    request.Method = "DELETE";
    request.ContentLength = contentLength;
    //request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentType = ContentType;

    return request;
}
```

Could you please point me where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try SetEntitySetAccessRule to AllRead, AllWrite, or other options:

```
public class WcfDataService1 : DataService< HenryContext >
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)

        {            

              config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);

             config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had what seems to be the same problem and it was due to WebDAV intercepting the requests. Removing the module for that application solved the problem.

On IIS 7:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

On IIS 6:

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    <!-- ... -->
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Sorry, this option did not solve my problem. FYI, I'm using IIS 6.0. When i searched the forum, this solution works out for IIS 7.0

Comment: Did you try the IIS 6 equivalent? (I edited my answer to add it)

Comment: Finally I solved it by adding Request Filtering on the site to allow the DELETE verb

Comment: Do you mind sharing your solution on how you configured Request Filtering to make it work?